# How Can MANUALLY import ECLIPSE COLOR THEME plugin in kepler

Tags: eclipse, colors, eclipse-plugin

I had tried all the steps given in net for getting color theme plugin in my eclipse. But i failed every time. Always I get the following error.

Error
Tue Dec 24 18:20:32 IST 2013
No repository found at http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update.

Artifact not found: http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update/content.jar.

Internal error logged from JDI Debug:

NEED A SOLUTION.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The URL is wrong. Use http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update/ as update site instead. Github [changed the domain](https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io) for the Github pages (where that plugin is hosted).